# Checkbox values not corresponding with row selection

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form with multiple rows selected.All the columns works fine but the checkbox values are not updated correctly.

```
 $data = $con->query($query);
  $data->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  foreach($data as $row){
   print " <tr> ";
   foreach ($row as $name=>$value){
   print " </p><br /><input type=text name='step[]' id=step value =$value size=80>
   <label for=correct>Correct:</label>
   <input type=hidden name='correct[]' id=correct value = 'Not Correct' checked>
   <input type=checkbox name='correct[]' id=correct value = 'Correct'>
   <label for=remark>Remark:</label>
   <input type=text name='remark[]' id=remark size=75>
   <input type=hidden name=date[] id=date value= $dateName>
   <input type=hidden name=time[] id=time value= $timeName>
   <input type=hidden name=type[] id=type value =$typeName>
   <input type=hidden name='resource[]' id=resource value ='$resourceName'>
   <input type=hidden name=location[] id=location value = $locationName >
   <input type=hidden name='submittedby[]' id=submittedby value= '$submittedby'> ";
   } // end field loop
   print " </tr> ";
  } // end record loop 
  print "</table> ";
  } catch(PDOException $e) {
   echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
  } // end try
```

This is the insert part:

```
$size = count($_POST['step']); 
$i = 0;
while ($i  < $size) { 
// define each variable 
$listno = $_POST['listno'][$i];
$date = $_POST['date'][$i];
$time = $_POST['time'][$i];
$type = $_POST['type'][$i]; 
$resource = $_POST['resource'][$i]; 
$location = $_POST['location'][$i]; 
$step = $_POST['step'][$i];
$correct =$_POST['correct'][$i];  
$remark = $_POST['remark'][$i];
$submittedby = $_POST['submittedby'][$i];
// do the update and print out some info just to provide some visual feedback 
$sql = "INSERT INTO feedback  (date, time, listno, type, resource, location, step, correct, remark, submittedby) VALUES ('$date', '$time', $listno, '$type', '$resource', '$location', $step, '$correct', '$remark', '$submittedby')"; 
if(mysqli_multi_query($link, $sql)){

       echo "Records added successfully.";

        } 
        else{

    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);

        }
print "<br />$date<br />$time<br />$listno<br />$type<br />$resource<br />$location<br />$step<br />$correct<br />$remark<br />$submittedby<br />"; 
++$i;
```

All the "Correct" values are inserted and then the "Not Correct" values but all the other columns are in record order.

Comment: If I change the input type from checkbox to text it works fine, some problem with the checkbox???????

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes are only successful controls if they are checked.

If a row has no checked checkboxes, then it won't get any results, and everything following it in the array will shuffle down a position to fill the gap.

So given:

```
<input type=hidden name='correct[]' id=correct value = 'Not Correct' checked>
<input type=checkbox name='correct[]' id=correct value = 'Correct'>
```

… if the checkbox is not checked then you'll insert one value into `$_POST['correct'][]` (from the hidden input) and if it isn't then you'll insert two (one from each input).

---

Don't depend on automatically indexed field names. Give them explicit names:

e.g.

```
name='correct[<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name); ?>]'
```

Do that for *every* field you have, not just the checkboxes.

You can then get the keys from `$_POST['step'][]`, and loop over that list of keys to pluck the matching values from `$_POST[$everything_else][$key]`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Decided to uses 2 check boxes and it solved the problem